# Is floating point division sufficient to determine bin number accurately?

Tags: floating-accuracy

I'm trying to account for crossings of the prime meridian accurately and
I ran into the following question about IEEE floating point arithmetic
(round to nearest):

Let *n* be an integer, and *d* a small positive number.  Does

*y* = *n* * 360 - *d* < *n* * 360

guarantee that floor(*y*/360) < *n*?  Here all the operations (* - < / floor) are to
be understood as floating operations (using e.g., double precision IEEE).

What about if 360 in this question is replaced by some other positive
floating point number.  (The same question arises whenever a floating
point quantity is being assigned to evenly spaced bins.)

Answer (score 0):

`n * 360 - d < n * 360` --> `0 - d < 0` --> `d > 0` is true because "*d* (is) a <strike>small</strike> positive number".

The value of `n` is irrelevant so far.

---

`y = n * 360 - d` -->  `y/360 = n - d/360` -->

With `0.0 <= q < 1.0`,
`floor(y/360) + q =  n - d/360` --> `floor(y/360) - n = -q - d/360`

For all values of `q` and `d`, `-q - d/360 < 0` -->

`floor(y/360) - n < 0` --> `floor(y/360) < n`. [Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)

---

If 360 was replaced by `x` as any integer greater than 0, the answer is still the same.  I *think* it is also true if `x` is replaced by any number >= 1.0.  Have to think about `0 < x < 1`.

The *smallest* of `d` is irrelevant so far - just that it is a positive number (`d > 0`).

Comment: Sorry, the inequality n * 360 - d < n * 360 was supposed to be
interpreted as "what you would get if you did all the operations using
floating point arithmetic".  So for sufficiently small d, e.g., 1.0e-30,
is inequality is only satisfied for n = 0 (using double).  I will edit
to question to clarify.

Comment: Let's jump to the higher level problem: "to account for crossings of the prime meridian accurately" In `C`, rather than use `y = n * 360 - d;` for some `n`, use `longitude = fmod(longitude, 360.0);` and suffer _no_ loss of precision regardless of `longitude`. [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928253/is-fmod-exact-when-y-is-an-integer)

Comment: Yes, I already use this (and I have to deal with the pesky problem that the result can lie in (-360,360)).  In my current application, I need to determine which period of longitude I'm in, i.e., floor(longitude/360).

Comment: @cffk `remainder((longitude, 360.0)` will give answer `-180 <= longitude <= 180`.  Also check `remquo()` will give the last 3 bits of the integer period.  Perhaps those may help.

Comment: thanks, noted.  But this still leaves my original question open.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I think I can provide a partial answer.  Let me
rephrase the question:  Write a function

```
int bin(double x, double m)
```

which computes

```
int(floor(x/m))
```

exactly.  Assume *m* is positive and that the result is in the range of
int.

The first attempt is

```
int bin0(double x, double m) {
  return int(std::floor(x / m));
}
```

but this fails for the case *m* = 360.0 and *x* = -denorm_min (0 is
returned instead of -1).

Since this failure is just for *x* close to zero, the second attempt is

```
int bin1(double x, double m) {
  int n = int(std::floor(x / m));
  return n == 0 && x < 0 ? -1 : n;
}
```

I *believe* this returns the exact answer *provided* that *n* * *m* is
exactly representable as a double.  For *m* = 360.0, this includes all
*n* representable as a 32-bit integer.  Am I right? A proof would be
nice!

If this condition doesn't hold, e.g., *m* = 0.1, then the best I can
come up with is

```
int bin2(double x, double m) {
  double z = std::fmod(x, m);
  return int(std::floor((x - z)/m + 0.5)) + (z < 0 ? -1 : 0);
}
```

Does this always return the correct result?  Is there some "cleaner"
solution?

**ADDENDUM:** In my application I only needed to get the parity of the
bin number (even or odd).  (My application is measuring the area of a
geodesic polygon and I need to keep track of whether an edge encircles
the pole an even or odd number of times.)  So chux's suggestion to use
remquo is a good one.  Unfortunately (1) std::remquo requires C++11 and
(2) more seriously, the glibc implementation of remquo is buggy; see
this [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17569).  So I end up doing essentially

```
int binparity(real x, real m) {
  // return the parity of int(floor(x/m))
  x = std::fmod(x, 2 * m);
  return (x >= 0 && x < m) || x < -m ? 0 : 1
}
```

Comment: (re: 2nd attempt) Let's assume `m >= 1.0`:  If `x/m` does not underflow to 0.0, `return int(std::floor(x / m)` obviously works.  If `x >= +0.0`, is works too.  The only case left is when `x < 0.0` and `x/m` underflows.  Code's `n == 0 && x < 0 ? -1 : n;` takes care of that.  The issues becomes more complicated if `m < 1.0`.  Suggest stating the range of `m`.  Do you care about `-0.0`?  Your approach returns 0.  Alternative when `m >= 1.0`: `double q = x/m; return floor(q ? q, x);`

Comment: Have doubt `int(std::floor((x - z)/m + 0.5)) ...` works in corner cases due to inexact quotient in `(x - z)/m + 0.5)`.

Comment: Maybe `int bin1x(double x, double m) { double q = x/m; return (int) floor(q ? q, -(x<0.0)); }` for any `m > 0`.