# Error while running program with certain operator and operands in C

Tags: c, output, operand

I was trying to run a program but it shows an error as:

> Invalid binary operator float to int

When I tried making it `float` it says:

> Invalid binary operator float to float

The problem is with `%` operator And its operands.

Please tell me what to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x,y;
    scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);
    float z=x%5.0f;
    if(x<=y && z==0)
        printf("%.2f",y-x-0.50);
    else if (x>y || z!=0)
            printf("%.2f",y);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: modulus operator `%` only applies between integers..

Comment: I changed the indentation to reflect how this is working.

Answer (score 4):

Modulus `%` only makes sense with integers because it is defined as the remainder from integer division.  You can't do integer division with floats.

Answer (score 4):

Modulus operator doesn't work with float.  You probably want to use the fmod function:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `%` operator doesn't work with `float`. Instead you need to use `fmod()` for your requirement.

```
double fmod(double numerator, double denominator);
```

Answer (score 1):

FMOD function is what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float x,y;
    double z;


    scanf("%f%f",&x,&y);

    z = fmod(x, 5.0f);

    if(x<=y && z==0)
        printf("%.2f",y-x-0.50);
    else if (x>y || z!=0)
            printf("%.2f",y);
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@amdixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370847/amdixon) commented: "modulus operator `%` only applies between integers."

> The operands of the `%` operator shall have integer type.
>   C11dr §6.5.5 2

In keeping with `float` arithmetic, suggest using `fmodf()` instead of `%` or `fmod()`.
`fmodf()` computes the floating-point remainder of `x/y`.

```
// float z=x%5.0f;
float z = fmodf(x , 5.0f);
```

Notes:

The result of `fmod()` and family can be expected to be exact.  [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929050/2410359)

The `%` is the *remainder*.  Calling it the modulus operator overloads its meaning that often does not meet expectations when with `a%b`, either `a` or `b` is negative.  See [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683563/2410359)