# Converting radians to degrees in a reference-circle manner

Tags: c, floating-point, range, radians

Context: I'm creating a map-replanner for a robot in C, it should add obstacles within the environment to the map depending on which IR-sensors are getting high readings.

For this i need to check how the robot is positioned IRL vs in the internal map (pointing north). But for some reason, i sometimes get negative values in the conversion. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

There should never be any negative values. The allowed values should lie between 0-360. As of now, i get negative values sometimes.

```
#define     PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950
#define     DEG(x)   (x*57.2957795130823208767981548141)
```

Code:

```
float currentRot  = now.th; //current rotation-reading in RAD from function.
if(currentRot > PI){        //normalize values       
   currentRot     = currentRot - 2 * PI;
}
if(currentRot < -PI){
   currentRot     = currentRot + 2 * PI;
}
currentRot        = fmod(currentRot,PI*2); //convert into RAD-modular
currentRot        = DEG(currentRot);       //convert to degrees
```

Any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @StoryTeller is right. And Joel, 400 reputation and not a minimal complete example? :/

Comment: @gsamaras updated. This is literally all that is needed for the conversion. Any further code is redundant

Comment: First you try to normalise the range to − _π_ < _x_ < _π_, then you apply `fmod`, whose result has the same sign as _x_. So why do you expect that there can't be any negative values?

Comment: (Your `DEG` macro should probably have parentheses around `(x)`, athough it doesn't matter in this case.)

Comment: Okay, this is off-topic since It's probably not the issue, but precomputing `180.0 / PI` just makes your code less clear to read. I assure you the compiler will turn the constant expression into it's final value. They are good at that.

Comment: @MOehm I'm not sure what you are saying here(1st comment). I normalize the values so that if i get a negative reading, i add two pi to the value (to make it the same value but positive).

Comment: Yes, but the limits of your normalisation aren't 0 and 2·π, which would correspond to 0° and 360°, but −π and π, which corresponds to −180° and 180°. Say your angle is 3/2 π. It is "normalised" to −1/2 π. `fmod(−1/2 π, 2 π)` will yield −1/2 π, which is then converted to −90°.

Comment: @MOehm oh, yes, you are correct. I used this logic to determine which way was the fastest to turn (which is just -180->180). Thought it had a general use without thinking it through. If you'd like you can post an answer and i'll approve it for you.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I would much rather use an inlined function then a macro, in every case where it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

π cannot be exactly represented as a `float`, so any mod-ding with `fmod(currentRot,PI*2);` or comparing `if(currentRot > PI){` may fail to provide the expected results for edge cases.

Note that `currentRot = currentRot + 2 * PI;` is a `(foat) + (double)` and the conversion to `float`.  The edges of this conversion are problem to avoid slight negative results.  Best to avoid mixing `float` and `double` math for this sensitive conversion.

---

Even with the good comment of [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm), the inexactness `PI` and mixing `float/double` math can result in negative `currentRot`.

Instead, convert radians to degrees first and then mod.

```
float RadianToDegree(float r);
  float d = (float)(PI/180.0) * r;
  d = fmodf(d, 360.0f);
  if (d < 0.0f) d += 360.0f;
  return d;
}
```

The result will be [0.0 - 360.0] inclusive.

Mod-ding by 360 can be expected to incur to no [round-off error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20928253/2410359).

Use `fmodf()` with `float` and `fmod()` with `double` to avoid unnecessary conversions.

---

On a higher level note, the goal of "The allowed values should lie between 0-360" sacrifice precision.  Consider  a primary range of between -180 - +180.

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
if(currentRot > PI){        //normalize values       
  currentRot     = currentRot - 2 * PI;
}
if(currentRot < -PI){
  currentRot     = currentRot + 2 * PI;
}
```

you try to normalize to -π < `currentRot` < π, and then you do:

```
currentRot = fmod(currentRot,PI*2);
```

which "Returns the floating-point remainder of numer/denom" ([ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/)), meaning that the sign of the result, will be the same.

This does not ensure that negative values are prohibited. I mean your range doesn't start from 0.

Comment: well, this isn't an answer to the question really. Here you are just stating the obvious :/