# Inverse of fmod

Tags: c++, math, division

If I have the following in C++ :

```
fmod(x, n) = o
```

how to restor **x** value from **o** ? when **n** value is known.

I have tried to use the normal mod where

```
a%b=c 
if a>=b then 
b+c -> a 
else 
c -> a
```

but that doesn't work when we are using floating point numbers

Comment: Can't be done, information has been lost

Comment: You can't invert `%` either. For instance, `n % 2 = 0` for all even numbers – the only information you get is that `n == k * 2` for some unknown `k`. Also, your method relies on already knowing the value of `a`, so...

Comment: `double frestore_x(double x, double n, double o) { return x; }`

Comment: Are you looking for a floating-point version of [std::div](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div)?

Comment: You can't.  Any specified values of `n` and `o` correspond to an infinite number of values of `x`.    You can get ONE of the possible values of `x`  (e.g. as `n + o`).    In general, `x` will be one of the values of `n + i * o` where `i` is any integral value.      It would be easier to simply save the original value of `x` before calculating `fmod(x, n)`.

Comment: The modulus is produced as the remainder after division. To go back you need the result of the division too, so (for integer arithmetic) q = x/n, r = x - q*n where r is x mod n and to go back x = r + q*n.

Comment: Does `x` have some limited set of values it takes on? Do you have a way of testing if a given guess of `x` is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this `std::fmod` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod):

> The floating-point remainder of the division operation `x / y` calculated by this function is exactly the value `x - rem * y`, where `rem` is `x / y` **with its fractional part truncated**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

Because the fractional part is truncated, it's impossible to get back the original value.

And that's before involving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: "that's before involving this." (_this_ being the limits of FP math) , while a general truism, need not apply here.  A good `fmod()` need not return _any_ precision loss. [result is exact by definition, even when the intermediate operations x/y, ... have inexact representations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929050/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

`fmod(x,10) = 0`

This counts for every integer number, ending on a zero, like 0, -10, 20, -30, ..., 100, -110, 120, -130, ..., 200, -210, 220, -230, ..., 300, -310, 320, -330, ..., 1000, -1010, 1020, -1030, ..., 1100, -1110, 1120, -1130, ... (you will also encounter ±123456789876543210 and ±98765432123456890 and many, many others) :-)

Do you see why your question can't have an answer? :-)

Comment: Same actually applies for integrals, too, there are so/too many `a` having `a % b == c`...

Answer (score 2):

In the following, I am assuming `double` computation, with `double` mapped to the IEEE-754 `binary64` format.

Any general division produces two pieces of information: the quotient and the remainder. `fmod (a, b)` delivers the remainder of `a / b` when the implicit quotient is converted to integer using rounding towards zero (truncation). The original dividend can be computed from the divisor `b`, the truncated quotient, and the remainder returned by `fmod()`, *provided the quotient is exactly representable* as a `double`. Without the quotient, there is not enough information to re-compute the dividend.

Since a `double` operand provides 52 stored significant (mantissa) bits, the quotient is in general only exactly representable if the difference of the binary exponents of the dividend and the divisor does not exceed 52. Obviously we need to avoid dividends and divisors that are infinity or NaN, and the divisor cannot be zero. Recomputing the dividend as (quotient * divisor + remainder) must be done with a single rounding, so a fused multiply-add (FMA) must be utilized.

The following program demonstrates the successful recomputation of the dividend under the restrictions stated. Note that achieving the intended functionality of `fdiv_rz()` requires configuring the compiler for the strictest IEEE-754 adherence. Otherwise, the compiler may consider the division operation as independent of the `fesetround()` calls, causing the order of operations to be changed such that the division is no longer sandwiched between the `fesetround()` calls as needed. From what I can see, this affects gcc in particular, whereas clang seems to be better behaved by default. I used the Intel compiler to build this code, which allows easy control of floating-point behavior. Specifically, I compiled with `icl /Qstd=c++11 /Ox /QxHOST /W4 /fp:strict fdiv_fmod.cpp`.

```c++
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#define N (2000000000)  // number of random test cases

/* divide a by b, rounding result towards zero */
double fdiv_rz (double a, double b) 
{
    double quot;
    int curr_mode = fegetround ();
    fesetround (FE_TOWARDZERO);
    quot = a / b;
    fesetround (curr_mode);
    return quot;
}

/* reinterpret 64-bit unsigned integer as an IEEE-754 binary64 */
double uint64_as_double (uint64_t a)
{
    double r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

/*
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J
  From: geo <gmars...@gmail.com>
  Newsgroups: sci.math,comp.lang.c,comp.lang.fortran
  Subject: 64-bit KISS RNGs
  Date: Sat, 28 Feb 2009 04:30:48 -0800 (PST)

  This 64-bit KISS RNG has three components, each nearly
  good enough to serve alone.    The components are:
  Multiply-With-Carry (MWC), period (2^121+2^63-1)
  Xorshift (XSH), period 2^64-1
  Congruential (CNG), period 2^64
*/
static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;
#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)

int main (void)
{
    double a, b, t, quot, rem;
    int expa, expb;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        do {
            a = uint64_as_double (KISS64);
        } while (isinf (a) || isnan (a));
        (void)frexp (a, &expa);
        do {
            b = uint64_as_double (KISS64);
            (void)frexp (b, &expb);
        } while ((b == 0) || isinf (b) || isnan (b) || (abs (expa - expb) > 52));
        
        quot = trunc (fdiv_rz (a, b));
        rem  = fmod (a, b);
        t = (fabs (quot) < 1.0) ? rem : fma (quot, b, rem);

        if (t != a) {
            printf ("a=% 23.13a  b=% 23.13a  quot=% 23.13a  rem=%23.13a  t=% 23.13a\n",
                    a, b, quot, rem, t);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    printf ("test passed\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The idea you demonstrated seems to be working. At least with integers its working fine. However, The code seems to be a little wired. There is a lot of lines that seems to be a little complicted.

Comment: What I havr understanded from you answer is if we were able to calculate the reminder and the quotient in a more accurate way. And then applied quotient * divisor + reminder would work fine ..