# Does math.sin/cos/tan use lookup tables?

Tags: lua

I am developing an application that requires fast accessing of sin/cos/tan values. Are the values provided by math precomputed or computed on the fly?

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is in computing sin/cos/tan values?

Answer (score 8):

No. Lua simply wraps the standard C sin/cos functions - see [lmathlib.c](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lmathlib.c.html)<sup>1</sup>

Using a look-up table only works for a relatively small discrete set of inputs and is not a general solution for such [continuous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function).

---

<sup>1</sup> The code for these wrapper functions follows the form

```c
static int math_sin (lua_State *L) {
  lua_pushnumber(L, l_tg(sin)(luaL_checknumber(L, 1)));
                      /* ^-- standard lib-C function */
  return 1;
}
```

As far as how the standard C functions are implemented, see
[How does C compute sin() and other math functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions)

Answer (score 4):

Consider making these functions local, as in

```
local sin = math.sin
```

After this, *if you have measured it and it is not fast enough*, then consider cacheing the values, if you frequently use the same inputs:

```
local function cache(f)
    local c={}
    return function (x)
        local y=c[x]
        if y==nil then
            y=f(x)
            c[x]=y
        end
        return y
    end
end

local sin = cache(math.sin)
local cos = cache(math.cos)
local tan = cache(math.tan)
```