# Getting different output for cout and printf while printing same variable

Tags: c++, printf, cout, trigonometry

Using Devc++ 
for printf getting 0.00000
and for cout getting some weird output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{
   float i,j=M_PI;
   i=sin(j);
   printf("%f \n",i);
   cout<<i;
}
```

Comment: It's not weird, [it's in scientific notation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07639be715a618c9)

Comment: Should be `int main()`.

Comment: What was this "weird output"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like `M_PI` isn't exactly pi (we know it can't be), and the result from `sin` isn't exactly zero.

`printf` with `%f` represents output numbers rounded as a "normal" decimal while `cout` uses an adaptive format (roughly `%g` in printf as I recall) that uses scientific notation to represent the small number.

Also note that `%f` means `double` but that the varargs helpfully promotes your `float` to a double when being passed in.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned you get different output values because the `cout` one uses scientific notation and the `printf` defaults to 6 decimal places. If you increase it by using

```
printf("%.013f \n",i);
```

You'll get the same value.

Now not all decimal numbers can be represented with floating point representation which is why you don't get the result you are expecting.

Also [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions) a question on how sin might be implemented on different platform, you can then see why sine of PI might not be 0.