# Intel x86_64 assembly, How to move between x87 and SSE2? (calculating arctangent of double)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, precision

I try to calculate arctangent of double precision float value, which I hold in xmm register. With normal float pointing it is possible to use old x87 instruction FPATAN, but how can I do this with double ?

Comment: The old x87 floating point stack has higher precision than the xmm registers, so you can just do the calculation there.

Comment: Then how can I move xmm value to that point stack??
fld xmm doesnt work at all

Comment: To move values between `[x/y/z]mm`-registers and the x87-stack, you need to use memory (usually the program stack).

Comment: using a good library is the best way. A properly designed SSE library is much faster than x87, not counting the time to move data between blocks

Comment: ["A decent vector math library should be ~10 or so times faster than the x87 transcendental functions (double precision) with errors on the order of ~1 to ~2 ulp."](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/), ["It turns out that the most optimized math libraries on x86 use SSE software implementations for sin and cos that are faster than the hardware instructions on the FPU"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions#comment2250614_2284952)

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21588

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* still copy data from xmm to x87 to use instructions like `fpatan`, but usually you should call a math library function.  (`fpatan` is so slow that replacing it with many simple instructions is still good.)  Wikipedia suggests looking at Netlib for a freely redistributable C implementation.  (Obviously the easiest way is to just call the function in libm on whatever system you're using.)

---

If you are going to do it, don't use static storage for the memory you bounce through; use a temporary on the stack.

Also note that [`fpatan` takes 2 inputs](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FPATAN.html), because it implements the [`atan2` library function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), giving a result in the appropriate quadrant depending on the sign of both inputs.

```
; assuming you did  sub  rsp, 24   or something earlier in your function

movsd   [rsp], xmm1
fld     qword [rsp]   ; st0 = xmm1
movsd   [rsp], xmm0
fld     qword [rsp]   ; st0 = xmm0,  st1 = xmm1

fpatan                ; st0 = arctan(xmm1/xmm0)

fstp    qword [rsp]     ; x87 stack is empty again
movsd   xmm0, [rsp]   ; xmm0 = arctan(xmm1/xmm0)

; and then   add rsp, 24   at some point before returning
```

Comment: Or in the x86-64 System V ABI, use `[rsp - 8]` or whatever space in the red-zone isn't in use.