# is javascript Math.sin() O(1)?

Tags: javascript, math, time-complexity

I am wondering if `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()` are O(1), and how is it translated to the compiler.

We can create a match table for it.

Or we can create a not so detailed match table and use a linear formula to calculate the value.

Or we can break it down.

I guess in any sense `Math.sin()` is sorta O(1) as the input is bounded, but how exactly is it done in the compiler and how complex it is?

Comment: it looks like a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions

Comment: It is `O(1)` (for *some* value of `C`), because it is has a [small] finite limit on instructions - even with Taylor expansion, eg. This doesn't mean every call is guaranteed to take the same amount of time (or not), but that's [not relevant to strict `O(1)` classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Javascript is an interpreted language. There is no compiler.

Comment: @Pyromonk There often is a compiler. See, e.g., https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/a-crash-course-in-just-in-time-jit-compilers/

Comment: I have found the C library, where I think they uses a Taylor's expansion to do so but it is O(1) time. However I am not exactly sure how JS does it. Also there is actually a difference in a lookup table and Taylor's expansion. In order to optimize the code sometimes a lookup table that calculated certain values of it might be more efficient.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, yes, [you are right](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/138521/is-javascript-interpreted-by-design). My knowledge was out of date. Thank you. In most cases it goes through an interpreter first still.

Comment: O(1) with respect to what?

Answer (score 1):

It might be impossible to give a definite answer, so I will try to provide you with as much information as I can instead.

The `Math` object implementations can differ between browsers and operating systems ("Note that many math functions have a precision that's implementation-dependent. This means that different browsers can give a different result, and even the same JS engine on a different OS or architecture can give different results.[<sup>[1]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)").

There are a few major ways in which a sine function can be implemented:

- [Taylor series approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Approximation_error_and_convergence)
- [CORDIC algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)

Complexity will depend on implementation. As far as I know, CORDIC algorithm is more common.