# Calculate sin(x) only using integers

Tags: java, trigonometry

I created a programming language for fun and now I want to write some basic math functions. The limitation I have is that the language only supports the integer data type. So I want to calculate 100 * sin(x). I've already managed to do the same thing with sqrt but I am stuck here. I've tried using the method described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2284929/6291515

And also a fast algorithm as described here: http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/07/18/fast-and-accurate-sinecosine-approximation/

I first tried modelling the algorithm in java (since it's easier to handle and debug) but it doesn't quite work. Maybe you have some idea on how to make it work.

```
int mult = 100;
int pi = (int)(Math.PI * (double) mult);
int x = (int)( 5 * (double) mult );
x = x % (2*pi);
int res=0, pow=x, fact=1, buf1 = pow;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  buf1 = pow;
  buf1 /= fact;
  res+=buf1;
  pow*=x;
  pow /= mult;
  pow*=x;
  pow /= mult;
  pow*=-1;
  fact*=(2*(i+1))*(2*(i+1)+1);
}
```

Comment: *...but it doesn't quite work*. What do you mean by that?

Comment: The results are seemingly arbitrary numbers

Comment: No time to write a good answer right now (maybe later), but have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC .  Also, your scaling of **x** looks very strange -- maybe you want to use degrees?  At least there are an even number of degrees in a circle.

Comment: I tried to wrap the radian value to -pi; +pi but I think I'll go for the easier 0; 2pi because it doesn't really work

Comment: Perhaps by the time you round Pi to only a couple of decimal places and keep rounding other intermediate results to 2 and rescaling, some numeric entropy may be setting in? An `int` isn't a very big number to store these power series terms when you're scaled by `mult`, and constantly trying to "unscale" each pass is going to cause inaccuracies. What's the purpose of the casts in `int x = (int)( 5 * (double) mult );`?