# Do the python numpy and sklearn trig functions use lookup tables to find the answers or do they try to compute values on-the-fly?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

How are the values of trig functions like `numpy.cos()` computed? Are lookup tables used to speed the process or does it try to actually compute cosine on-the-fly to some level of accuracy? Is this the same for sklearn, like `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does C compute sin() and other math functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions)

Comment: Numpy uses C functions for such computations... For information on the C implementation see the duplicate link above. Sklearn usually uses numpy functions. However, in the particular case of `cosine_similarity` no trigonometric functions are ever computed.