# What is the algorithm used for approximating trigonometric functions in RStudio?

Tags: r, function-approximation

I've tried the below code on RStudio and was expecting 0, 1 and 0.5 to show up. However, it showed a very small number instead of 0 and I thought it must be using some algorithm to approximate the sin function.

```
sin(c(pi, pi/2, pi/6))
```

This was the result

```
1.224606e-16 1.000000e+00 5.000000e-01
```

I wanted to know how they approximated the sin function in this case.

Comment: It's not the algorithm that's approximated, it's `pi`. It's only approximate because your computer has only finite RAM.

Comment: @Hugh Yes `pi` is approximated but also algorithm for computing `pi` as sine is a transcendental function :-) @Hithesh See R documentation for trig functions. You'll find references

Answer (score 0):

Though your question may seem simple at first, the reality is quite the opposite. Whenever you want to know what a function is doing, you just have to access the function as it were an object (it literally is an object in R):

```
sin # function (x)  .Primitive("sin")
```

.Primitive is one of the ways R can call C. If you want to see the C-code, then you can use the pryr library as in:

```
pryr::show_c_source(.Primitive(sin(x)))
# do_math1 with op = 21
```

It also opens a Github page with the code of arithmetic.c, the arithmetic heart of R. R computes sin with the do_math1 function with option 21. If you want to go any further, you will need to understand how the sin function is estimated in C. For that, I recommend the following post:

[How does C compute sin() and other math functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions)