# i wondering How does the math.sin algorithm work internally?

Tags: math

in c#

angle = 90
x = angle * pi(3.14...) / 180  --- convert to radian "x value is 1.5768..."

and
y = math.sin(x)  --- "y value is 1"

i know "sin(x) = y/r" and

if r = 1

sin(x) = y

what happening in math.sin argorithm internally

i have to know math.sin(x) for next step

Comment: The usual method used to compute sin & cos is the CORDIC method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC

Comment: Hint: read up on [`CORDIC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC)

Comment: @PicaudVincent - the same wiki article compares CORDIC to standard C libraries, which leads me to believe that the C libraries (that C# uses) are not CORDIC. Here is the quote "CORDIC is indeed faster than interpolating table based implementations such as the ones provided by the ARM CMSIS and C standard libraries.[54]"

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2284860/13813219

Comment: @rkdnrrl It is system-dependent and you will have to go to the detail (see JAlex comment). However, for sure, such robust routines to compute elementary functions are far from trivial to implement.