# __builtin_sinf What is it? Where is it? How do I obtain the dissassembly of it?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, x86-64, disassembly

I was curious this morning to see if I could obtian and understand the machine instructions generated for calculating a mathematical function such as `sin`, which as far as I am aware there is no machine instruction (in `x86-64`) for computing.

I first went to Godbolt and tried to obtian the disassembly for this:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
#include <cmath>
int mysin(float num) {
    float result = sin(num);
    return result;
}
```

I found that the output sets up some registers for a function call and then does `call sin`.

I then went and searched my local machine for the `cmath` headers. I found one in `/usr/include/c++/10/cmath.h`

This header calls another function: `__builtin_sin`.

My *guess* would be that the gcc compiler sees this identifier and substitutes it for some set of machine instructions which is somehow "baked into" the gcc compiler itself. Not sure if I am correct about that however.

I did a search of my system for the string `__builtin_sinf` and it doesn't look like there is any text file on the system which contains source code (C, asm or otherwise) which might then be used by a compiler.

Can anyone offer any explaination as to what `__builtin_sinf` is, where it is located if it exists in a file on my system, and finally how to obtain the disassembly of this function?

Comment: There is an x86 instruction for sine calculation: [FSIN](https://mudongliang.github.io/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_114.html).

Comment: @AdrianMole Does `__builtin_sin` get replaced by a call to `fsin` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I can't see why it wouldn't be.

Comment: Why does your title say `__builtin_sinf` when the body of the post asks about `__builtin_sin`? Why is the question tagged C when `#include <cmath>` shows it is using C++?

Comment: @AdrianMole `FSIN` is x87 and no one uses it nowadays unless you're the 80-bit `long double`. Modern x86 code uses SSE instead

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have the source code for the compiler on your system, then you probably do not have the source code for `__builtin_sin` because what to do for `__builtin_sin` is built into the compiler.

`__builtin_sin` is not an instruction to the compiler to replace it with a call to a `sin` routine. It tells the compiler that the operation of the standard C library `sin` function is desired, with all the semantics of the `sin` function defined by the C standard. This means the compiler does not have to replace a use of `__builtin_sin` with a call to `sin` or a call to any other function. It may replace it with whatever code is appropriate. For example, given some `__builtin_sin(x)`, if the compiler can determine the value of `x` during compilation, it can calculate `sin(x)` itself and replace `__builtin_sin(x)` with that value. Alternatively, the compiler can compile `__builtin_sin(x)` into assembly language that computes `sin`. Or it can compile `__builtin_sin(x)` into a call to the `sin` routine. It could also compile `__builtin_sin(x)` to a single machine instruction, such as `fsin`. (However, `fsin` is a primitive instruction with some limitations, particularly on argument domain, and is generally not suitable to serve as a `sin` function by itself.)

So there is no source file that contains the implementation of `__builtin_sin` other than the compiler’s source code. And, while that source code might contain information about an inline implementation of `sin` that the compiler uses, that information might not be in the form of assembly language for your target processor; it might be in the form of an internal compiler language specifying what operations to perform to calculate `sin`. (This is called an [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation).)

Comment: > *Or it can compile __builtin_sin(x) into a call to the sin routine.* Isn't this a circular argument? What do you mean by "sin routine" here? I am guessing not the same `sin(x)` C++ function.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: “The `sin` routine” means the `sin` routine in the standard C library.

Comment: Ok, so a C routine which I guess is different to the C++ routines which I found in the directory path I gave in the question?

Comment: This raises another question actually: Where might I find the C routine, if such a thing exists on my system?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant: In `/lib/libm.so`.  You can disassemble the binary, or you can look at glibc's source code, if you want to see what code runs for runtime-variable values where the compiler can't do constant-propagation through it.

Comment: Typically, one implementation of `sin` is used by both C and C++ implementations. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions) has information about some implementations. An implementation that Apple used is [here](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/Libm/) in Libm-315.tar.gz, in the file Source/Intel/sincostan.c.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've downloaded glibc from github and I'm completely baffled by the source. I assume I should be looking in the `math` subdirectory. I haven't found anything in there which is obviously source code for the `sin` routine. That includes looking at the makefile, which I can't honestly say I understood in detail because of the heavy use of macros

Comment: Here is sin https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c#L200

Comment: woboq has a somewhat out of date copy of the source, but a nice browser for navigating `#include` as a hyperlink and a good search. 
 https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch/s_sin-fma.c.html seems to include https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c.html .