# Where is Rust source for sin() cos()?

Tags: rust, standards, trigonometry

I looked into the source of Rust compiler, looking for the sin() and cos() functions of the f64 type and I cannot find it. It looks like there is just a reference to an intrinsic function, which does not have any body. So, is sin() implemented as a CPU instruction? Please guide me here.

Comment: It's system dependent. You should read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions?rq=1).

Comment: I think that's the part that passes it through to LLVM as an intrinsic: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/3e51277fe638dc0c8ceb6d1d3acc5aa247277c29/compiler/rustc_codegen_llvm/src/intrinsic.rs#L36 Just a wild guess, though, I'm not an expert in how the Rust compiler works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f32::sin` [compiles to](https://godbolt.org/z/7ahP8rYxo) the [`llvm.sin.f32`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html?highlight=llvm%20sin%20f32#llvm-sin-intrinsic) intrinsic, which compiles to a call to the `sinf` function in the C standard library.

`cos` and `tan`, and their `f64` equivalents, likely do something similar.