# Can I limit float precision?

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I'm coding a short demo in Canvas using JS, and it's not running as smoothly as it should,mostly because there are quite a bunch of sines and cosines involved.

I need to make those calculations to draw things to the screen. The thing is, I don't need 7 decimals to know a pixel position (Two would already be overkill), so i was thinking maybe it would run a bit faster if I could limit float operations to two decimal places. ¿Is that even possible?

Comment: I refer you to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3842276/1702990) as to why it's probably not possible. TLDR; It's probably implemented in hardware. You could try writing your own approximation however.

Comment: Computation speed is not related to the number of decimals. If you're calling trig functions a lot in a tight loops, consider a pre-filled lookup table (populated once on page load).

Comment: Also, this is the sort of micro-optimising which reeks of not having used some form of profiler

Answer (score 0):

You can draw faster if you stick to integers. For example, you can [draw a circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) using integer-based arithmetic.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have integers :(

Comment: Still, may be a good idea to stick to arithmetically "lighter" algorithms (e.g., the same example, with drawing a circle without extracting the square root).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to modify the precision of a floating point type: they are fixed by hardware (and typically language standards). In a different language, you might be able to use a lower-precision type (e.g., in C you could use a `float` instead of a `double`), but that's not possible in JavaScript, as all numbers are doubles.

What you could do is use a faster approximation to the sine function. Typically, a sin/cos function consists of two steps:

1. a "range-reduction" to find an integer n and float y on the interval [-π/4,π/4] such that x=n*π/2+y. This can't be performed using a standard mod (`%`) operation, as π can't be represented exactly by a floating point number.
2. a "kernel" function to compute the appropriate sin/cos, typically using a polynomial approximation.

(you can see the V8 source [here](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/4a709dd65837edd10c60c68e47ae8dc9727ecc33/src/third_party/fdlibm/fdlibm.js)).

So there are couple of things you can do:

- Use arguments that are already reduced to the appropriate interval, or alternatively, use an approximate reduction (i.e. `y = x % Math.PI/2`)
- Use a faster (and less accurate) approximation to sin/cos: there's lots of stuff about this on the web, e.g. [here](http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=205).