# Which Algorithms are used in java.lang.Math?

Tags: java, math

I'm wondering which algorithms are used to implement math functions from the java.lang.Math class?

For example, is sin(x)(or log(x)) implemented as sum of elements of Taylor series or any other algorithm?

Comment: most probably it uses fpu instructions. why to reinvent bicycle? Also depends on VM implementaion

Comment: @Joey here is a surprise for you http://siyobik.info/index.php?module=x86&id=114

Comment: @Andrey - "it probably uses ..." is probably not good enough.  It also begs the question - what algorithm do the FPU instructions use?

Comment: @Stephen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345085/how-do-trigonometric-functions-work/345117#345117

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're native. That means it's probably C code which just calls the FPU to do the work.

See:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Math.java.html

God bless

Answer (score 0):

You can get a java library for systems which don't have native support for these methods, however most JVM use the underlying machine code instructions to do these.

Answer (score 0):

See "Elementary Functions: Algorithms and Implementation" by Jean-Michel Muller.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it is vendor and platform dependent.  Here's what the `Math` class javadoc says on the subject:

> *"Unlike some of the numeric methods of class StrictMath, all implementations of the equivalent functions of class Math are not defined to return the bit-for-bit same results. This relaxation permits better-performing implementations where strict reproducibility is not required."*
>
> *"(By default many of the Math methods simply call the equivalent method in StrictMath for their implementation.) Code generators are encouraged to use platform-specific native libraries or microprocessor instructions, where available, to provide higher-performance implementations of Math methods. Such higher-performance implementations still must conform to the specification for Math."*

The chances are that a typical JVM will implement the operations as calls to C libraries that in turn use FPU instructions where available.  But you can't generalise ...

If you want to math operations where the algorithms are tightly specified, you need to use `StrictMath` rather than `Math`.  The `StrictMath` versions of the operations are (I understand) guaranteed to give the same answers on any Java platform.  The downside is that they are most likely slower.