# How are sin(x) or cos(x) in math.h implemented?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math.h

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does C compute sin() and other math functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions)

I'm curious how `sin` and `cos` the are implemented on a low level.

I just had a look inside the math.h and couldn't find the declaration for `sin` and `cos`.  But since this was a dead end to me, I'm turning to you, SO.

I would like to know how many operations it takes to calculate a sine and what tricks are used for speed-up. Are they implemented differently on different hardware and are there processors that support this as a native instruction? How fast are they compared to an addition, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284860/how-does-c-compute-sin-and-other-math-functions

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345085/how-do-trigonometric-functions-work/345117#345117

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I must have used the wrong terms to find an answer before!

Comment: This is near impossible to answer in total. Generally, the answer would be Taylor, and roughly as much as ~200-300 additions, but this can greatly vary depending on platform and required precision (imagine a lookup table, for example). I've seen implementations that run in ~24 cycles on x86_64 with 99% the same precision as reference.