# power series expansion for sine function

Tags: python

```
import math


def sine_func(x):
    power = 0
    sine = x
    add = (-1)**(power)*(x**(2*power+1))/(math.factorial((2*power+1)))
    while math.fabs(add) > 1.0e-8:
        sine += add        
        power += 1
        add == (-1)**(power)*(x**2*power+1)/(math.factorial((2*power+1)))

return sine
```

print(sine_func(1))

Program is just running forever, any thoughts on where I made my error?

Comment: you should remove the underscore after `add_` in line 8.

Comment: ... and perhaps that last "`==`" should be something else? ... and sine() vs sine_func()? Sounds like this isn't actually your code..

Comment: oops, thanks, i changed some variable names to make for easier readability on the forums, but still produces the same problem though

Comment: Why would I remove the "==", i want to set add equal to that

Comment: I couldn't make the code run OOTB ... and add seems to always be one.

Comment: I made some changes for easier readability because i had to have long ass names for class, i think i fixed all the naming errors though

Comment: Code runs fine. But the value is maybe wrong.

Comment: Actually, repeatedly calculating the power and factorial is not a good idea, it would be better to remember the actual value of them and simply adjust them for each iteration. This will save tons of calculation time. Additionally [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/345117/589206).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.  We have to use power series approximation though

Comment: Just compared my version to yours and it performs 25% faster, so the speedup is modest. Still a speedup :) [both versions use a Taylor series].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running fine for me (Python 3.3.3), after fixing the brackets and the initialization as `sine=0`.

```
import math

def sine_func(x):
    power = 0
    sine = 0
    add = (-1)**(power)*(x**(2*power+1))/(math.factorial((2*power+1)))
    while math.fabs(add) > 1.0e-8:
        sine += add        
        power += 1
        add = (-1)**(power)*(x**(2*power+1))/(math.factorial((2*power+1)))
return sine
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
add_ == (-1)**(power_int)*(x**2*power_int+1))/(math.factorial((2*power_int+1)))
```

Neither refers to the previous variable (`"add" != "add_"`) nor assigns any value - `==` is comparison in Python, not assignment. Try:

```
add = (-1)**(power_int)*(x**2*power_int+1))/(math.factorial((2*power_int+1)))
```